# Why is my iPhone 6 wireless working on b/g mode?

Tags: iphone, wifi

My router is AirPort Time Capsule which supports wireless ac. My iPhone is an iPhone 6 that also supports ac mode.

I was looking at data in AirPort Utility and for my phone it was showing it is on mode 802.11 b/g which I think is old and slow but my iPad 3 was on 802.11 a/n mode.

Does that mean there is something wrong with my iPhone wireless?

Comment: How can you check it on your Airport Utility?

Comment: @jherran the version of the application on iPad shows these info.

Comment: can't see where on iPad, iPhone nor OS X app.

Comment: @jherran only in iPad...when it lists the wireless clients, select one of them, these are the devices currently connected to the router, then click on its network connection status to show more info about it, it will show Data Rate, RSSI and Mode

Answer (score 1):

Most routers/AP will step down to b/g when there is a device on the network that does not support N or AC. Often this is a printer, or Roku or something you have on the network. Examine all the clients and devices to determine which are causing the router to step down, and either reconfigure, upgrade or eliminate them. Also, there may be an outside device on your wireless network causing similar issues.

Alternatively, you can configure your Airport to work in N mode only. Open the Airport Utility, select Wi-fi Settings, Radio Mode and change the mode for 2.4GHz. This is also a good way to see what devices might be incompatible with the faster speeds your router supports.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your Airport Time Capsule have the same name for 2.4GHz and 5GHz.

To solve it, just go to Wireless Options… and change the 5GHz network name.

On your iDevice replace the old wifi network with the new one and should work.

Source: [How to force 802.11ac?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=18718569&postcount=6)

Comment: My network names are different, picked the 5Hz for myself and 2.4 for roommate. but ok thanks, will read that post more carefully to see if there is something I can do

Comment: Your router can't be connecting in b/g on the 5 GHz band, so it's clearly using a 2.4GHz network.